# iOS Application failed codesign verification. codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from

Tags: ios, build, code-signing

I'm really pulling my hair at this very annoying problem, 
I usually build new apps for the App Store without issues, but this time it just doens't work.

The weird thing is when i just do "Build" for "Release", it works with no problem, but when i do "Archive" for "Release", it shows the following error

`warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/freak4pc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-atlgyhqdbhtnxvdnpfikhboujfpu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp
AssertMacros: message,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 554
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 918
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/freak4pc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-atlgyhqdbhtnxvdnpfikhboujfpu/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/embedded.m
 - (null)`

My provisioning profile should be working perfectly, as the Organizer also recognizes it as valid. My Entitlements only have a get-task-allow set to NO value, which i always use on successful builds.

I've tried just about anything except for removing my keys and recreating them, which I'd rather not do - since this is the only app i have problem building.

Tried:

```
1. Recreating the Entitlements
2. Redownloading the Provisioning profile
3. Do a complete clean including Clean Build Folder
4. Edit the pbxproj file and clearing all the entielements and signing option and re-setting them
```

Anything i'm missing?

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using?

Comment: 4.3.1 , The weird thing is I just built 3 apps yesterday with no issues, This is just a bit of an old app we've built so maybe some configuration got corrupted on the way...

Comment: For older Xcode projects, it sometimes helps to remove user-specific build-settings (everything within the xcodeproj-bundle that has a user-name).

Comment: I dont have any settings like that unfortunately ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The 'embedded.m' at the end of the last Line should be 'embedded.mobileprovision'. It's caused by the Line length being exceeded and the command being truncated.

I had the same problem and solved it by shortening the app name. You may want to try something similar. Basically anything that makes that last command line shorter so it's not truncated.

Richard

Comment: This is seriously the dumbest bug I've ever seen in Xcode. Thanks alot man :)

Comment: Unbelievable, +1 thank you for the answer. This still happens in Xcode 4.3.2 !

Comment: Can short my app name. If I do like that can I solve my issue

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This bother me for weeks after upgrade to Xcode 4.3.2.

Answer (score 3):

You might not want to shorten your app name. An alternative is...

In Xcode->Behaviors->Edit Behaviors->Locations: change Derived Data to a custom file path (drop down menu), and then create a shorter file path. My files were embedded in a few folders, and I saved myself characters by moving the derived data folder closer to my home dir.

Renaming the project is kinda scary because it caused problems with my source control (although I'm no expert with Git).

Comment: I shortened my app name (a hassle in and of itself), but it wasn't enough.  I followed the advice here to shorten my Derived Data location to "/tmp/Xcode/DerivedData", and it worked!  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem. All my provisioning Profiles, Certificates, Bundle Identifier every thing was perfect. Except My Apps Executable file Name in Info.Plist and Product Name in Target Build Settings was slightly different. And just because of that codesign_wrapper was not able locate Provisioning. I spend nearly one day to figure this out.

**So Please do one check App Product Name is have to be same with your Executable file in Info.Plist.**

Comment: There's no necessity of having the Product Name identical to the Executable File, many of my apps don't do this.

Comment: Yes Shai you was right And it some time fails if Executable name haves special chars or symbols

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've chosen the right certificate in **Code Signing Identity** if you are working on several apps. 
This was my case.